# Remove data.table rows whose vector elements contain nested NAs

Tags: r, data.table

I need to remove from a data.table any row in which column `a` contains any `NA` nested in a vector:

```
library(data.table)

a = list(as.numeric(c(NA,NA)), 2,as.numeric(c(3, NA)), c(4,5) )
b <- 11:14

dt <- data.table(a,b)
```

Thus, rows 1 and 3 should be removed.

I tried three solutions without success:

```
dt1 <- dt[!is.na(a)] 
dt2 <- dt[!is.na(unlist(a))]
dt3 <- dt[dt[,!Reduce(`&`, lapply(a, is.na))]]
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
dt[sapply(dt$a, \(l) !any(is.na(l)))]
```

This alternative also works, but you will get warnings

```
dt[sapply(dt$a, all)]
```

Better approach (thanks to r2evans, see comments)

```
dt[!sapply(a,anyNA)]
```

Output:

```
     a  b
1:   2 12
2: 4,5 14
```

A third option that you might prefer: You could move the functionality to a separate helper function that ingests a list of lists (`nl`), and returns a boolean vector of length equal to `length(nl)`, and then apply that function as below. In this example, I explicitly call `unlist()` on the result of `lapply()` rather than letting `sapply()` do that for me, but I could also have used `sapply()`

```
f <- \(nl) unlist(lapply(nl,\(l) !any(is.na(l))))

dt[f(a)]
```

Comment: `any(is.na(.))` can be reduced to `anyNA(.)`, which means your first expression can be reduced to `dt[!sapply(a, anyNA),]` for the same results (and better code-golf). (And since this is `data.table`, no need for `dt$`.)

Comment: that's a good addition @r2evans.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to *apply()

```
dt[, .SD[!anyNA(a, TRUE)], by = .I][, !"I"]

#         a     b
#    <list> <int>
# 1:      2    12
# 2:    4,5    14
```